# How should I save data while is uploading some data with NSURLSession and the app is suspended?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am developing an app where I have to upload an entity with its relation. (I think this is similar to dropbox files uploading) This entity is called `PlaceEntity` and has a relation with `PictureEntity (to many)`. I want to do it using `NSURLSession` to handle the upload while the app is **suspended**. So, what I am doing is I create the `uploadTasks` for place pictures, and I start them. After each picture upload I have to receive data and save some information in the `pictureEntity`. When all the pictures are uploaded I create a new task and I save the place in the server.

I have tested it in `background and foreground` and everything works fine. The problem is when I suspend the app. The upload picture requests are executed(I know because I watch the request with Charles MAC OS app) the problem happens when I have to update the information in `core data`, after each upload. The method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

never is called because my app is completely out. I can't then update Core Data or launch a new request.

Any idea??

Thank you